# Quasi-relativistic dispersion relation in solid state physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

I recently worked on a question where I was asked to find the fermi energy for a 2D solid by considering an electron gas with fermi-dirac statistics. It was based on content of chapter 4 of Steve Simon's Solid State Basics, and the solution was basically exactly the same as that entire chapter except there was a different dispersion relation that was specified in the question. The book uses $E=\hbar^2 k^2/2m$ but I was told to use something that was supposedly "quasi relativistic," according to the text of the question. It was $E(\mathbf{k})=\hbar v|\mathbf{k}|$ for some constant velocity $v$.

What makes this quasi-relativistic for electrons in a 2d solid? What assumptions would it take for one to derive that? It seems to be like a weird mix of a classical $\omega=vk$ and a quantum mechanical $E=\hbar\omega$.